# How to add filtering to find users by City, Gender, Photo and Age?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Index view, I want to be able to filter users based on city, gender, photo and age. Currently I only have filtering by age. I want the options for City and Gender to be in a select list and the photo should be a checkbox.

Here is my filter form:

```
<form action="/users" method="get">
Ages from: <input id="min_age" name="[min_age]" type="text" class="gteq" />
to <input id="max_age" name="[max_age]" type="text" class="gteq" />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

Here is Users Controller:

```
def index
@users = User.all
if params[:min_age] && params[:max_age]
@users = @users.where("profiles.birthday >= ? AND profiles.birthday <= ?",
 params[:max_age].to_i.years.ago + 1.day, params[:min_age].to_i.years.ago)
end
end
```

City, Gender and Photo are all attributes of the Profile model which `belongs_to` Users. Each User `has_one` Profile.

I want all filtering options to be optional. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails, relations can be chained.

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  if params[:min_age] && params[:max_age]
    @users = @users.where("profiles.birthday >= ? AND profiles.birthday <= ?",
    params[:max_age].to_i.years.ago + 1.day, params[:min_age].to_i.years.ago)
  end

  if params[:city]
    @users = @users.where("profiles.city = ?", params[:city])
  end

  if params[:gender]
    @users = @users.where("profiles.gender = ?", params[:gender])
  end

  ......
end
```

Although , it is ugly....
If you persist to write filters, I suggest you encapsulte the logic to model and use scope.
Or you can try a good gem named [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack). You will find it has done the most of works for you , you just need a little customization or not.

Comment: and what will be the output if all params will be sent to controller? If I'll want to filter for age and city at the same time, how your code will work in this case? On the other hand, Ransack is great.